# How do I Apply a simple script to a specific tab in a Google Sheet? I know zero code

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm trying to apply this script to a specific tab to not ruin all the other tabs.

```
function onEdit(e) {

  let range=e.range;
  let activeRow = range.getRow();
  let activeColumn = range.getColumn();
  let cellValue = range.getValue();
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();


    if (activeColumn == 9) {

      if (cellValue == false) {

          sheet.getRange(activeRow,8).clearContent();

      } else {

          sheet.getRange(activeRow,8).setValue(new Date());

      }

    }
  
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). See [Apps Script at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Sheet.getName()`, like this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.columnStart !== 9
    || e.range.getSheet().getName().match(/^(Sheet1|Sheet2)$/i)) {
    return;
  }
  e.range.offset(0, -1)
    .setValue(e.value === 'FALSE' ? null : new Date());
}
```